# Same dates for publish and post

Tags: nodes

I am using the published date module.

The posted date, and published date are the same for the nodes. Does anyone know any reason why that is so?

Comment: By default in Drupal node has two dates - created and changed. Can you provide screenshot to get know about what "published" date are you spoken about. THis date can be added by some module.

Comment: I am not familiar with this module, but i think that published date is equal to post date by default to make node published at once if you don't specified any custom published date. I advice you to check settings of that module - maybe you can setup any other date to be default value.

Comment: May you provide the link to the project page on Drupal.org for the module you are using? It can help with answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The publish date can change, like after unpublishing and republishing some content. The post date is rather fixed, it's the date the content is created...

Comment: What I wanted was to have several dates on the same node: when the node was initially created and when the node was published. The simplest was was to edit the node.module file. Change the line ($variables['date']      = format_date ($node->created);
  $variables['name']      = theme('username', array('account' => $node));)to( $variables['date']      = format_date ($node->published_at);
  $variables['name']      = theme('username', array('account' => $node));"

Comment: @CrawleyObara: altering a core module? Really bad idea.

Comment: Sk8erPeter I had no other option.